# What is with this shvil?

Tags: chabad, chassidic-rebbe

I live in the Lubavitch section of crown heights, but am not chasidish myself. I know that 770 is disallowing the shvil that the meshichist bochurim keep. Can someone explain this to me? Is it true it is a pathway that they "protect" for the rebbe to spiritually walk?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Ezra and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us! Unfortunately, your question is very likely to get closed as we handle questions of Judaism, not "Jewish affairs" or "Jewish news". But hopefully you will find other questions of interest to ask and answer

Answer (score 3):

The Shvil or "pathway" is what was created to allow The Rebbe to enter and exit 770 for davening or other times that there was a large crowd and a "pathway" was made for The Rebbe to walk through to his intended destination.

Unfortunately, in the aftermath of The Rebbe's passing, there has been a resurgence of quacky ideology, one of which is that The Rebbe is still physically present and therefore the necessity to create a pathway for his entrance during times (such as davening) that he would "need" to enter.

That is what "the Shvil" is without mentioning the infighting regarding the lunacy of it.

Comment: True to some extent, but many probably see it as a testament to his spiritual presence and the hope for his return, similar to how the Rebbe himself continued to sit beside the Rayatz's empty chair when conducting meals in his apartment long after his passing.

Comment: Sitting next to an empty chair was because no one was going to sit the the Rayatz chair...